# Should I plug out my laptop after shutting it down?

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, battery-life

I have 5 Lenovo ideapad 330 laptops in my office and developers work with them. Laptops are plugged in all the time when they are working. My first question: Is it correct usage of laptops?

And the second question is: After they have done and I want to close the office, should I plug-out them or I can just leave them plugged in all the time?(24/7)

Comment: random link: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/leave-laptop-plugged-time/ . You will get several different opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, generally not a good idea. Use on battery about half the time and on AC about half the time. Leaving the machine always plugged in can reduce overall battery life and also the ability to hold charge. Not always but it can happen.
2. When the laptop is off, I always unplug them. This is an extension of point 1 above.